# Why is : $ g \circ f = ( \mathrm{pr}_{XZ}^{XYZ} )_* \big( ( \mathrm{pr}_{XZ}^{XYZ} )^* . \mathrm{pr}_{YZ}^{XYZ} )^* g \big) $?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, intersection-theory

Let $ \mathcal{E} (k) $ be the enumerative category of smooth projective varieties over a field $k$.
This is a $ \mathbb{Q} $ - linear category which has for objects : smooth projective varieties over $k$, and for morphismes the algebraic correspondances of degree $ 0 $ modulo the numerical equivalence as follows :

$$ \mathcal{E} (k) (X,Y) = \{ \ \text{ algebraic cycles ( with rational coefficients ) of codimension } \ \mathrm{dim} X \\ \mathrm{over} \ X \times Y \ \} / \sim_{ \mathrm{num} } $$

In a textbook which i'm learning right now, the author states that :

The composition of morphisms of $  \mathcal{E} (k) (X,Y) $ is given by the following law :
$$ g \circ f = ( \mathrm{pr}_{XZ}^{XYZ} )_* \big( ( \mathrm{pr}_{XZ}^{XYZ} )^* . \mathrm{pr}_{YZ}^{XYZ} )^* g \big) $$
Could you tell me why is :
$$ g \circ f = ( \mathrm{pr}_{XZ}^{XYZ} )_* \big( ( \mathrm{pr}_{XZ}^{XYZ} )^* . \mathrm{pr}_{YZ}^{XYZ} )^* g \big) $$
?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried writing down what you think composition should be? You’ll end up with what is given after some simple manipulations.

Comment: I don't know how to do this. :-)

Comment: First off, there's a typo in your composition formula. Second, have you tried anything? Do you know how a correspondence works? Do you know about the projection formula?